# oracle stored procedures encryption key

Tags: oracle

How to update stored procedures encryption key in oracle 11g.

```
(val IN varchar) RETURN varchar AS 
   outstr varchar(10); 
   descr varchar(255); 
BEGIN 
  -- Encryption Key For Encryption 
  secret_code := '123456788765432112345678'; 
  --create instance of OLE object on an instance of SQL Server; 
 success = 0 
 EXEC rc = sp_OACreate 'CAPICOM.EncryptedData', object OUT 
 if rc <> 0 
   begin 
      exec sp_oageterrorinfo object, src out, descr out end 
      method_call := 'SetSecret("' + Secret_code + '")' 
      RETURN (outstr); 
  END;
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context?  Is this a stored procedure you wrote that calls DBMS_CRYPTO?

Comment: (val IN varchar)
RETURN varchar
AS
outstr varchar(10);
   
   descr varchar(255);

BEGIN 

-- Encryption Key For Encryption
secret_code := '123456788765432112345678';

--create instance of OLE object on an instance of SQL Server; success = 0
EXEC rc = sp_OACreate 'CAPICOM.EncryptedData', object OUT
 if rc <> 0
  begin
  exec sp_oageterrorinfo object, src out, descr out 
  
  end
method_call := 'SetSecret("' + Secret_code + '")'

RETURN (outstr);
END;

Comment: i need to update this Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code with some other value.How can i do that.

Comment: Not sure what code you are posting. Some of it looks like SQL Server and some of it looks like PL/SQL. I suggest you really put some effort into fully describing your situation.

Comment: This is database schema the code which i gave is present at the functions -> decrypt data 
and i want to update the secret code value .i think u got my situation

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you looking for.
[Check this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-security-100258.html)

and also you may review  [this too](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/TablespaceEncryption_11gR1.php)

Comment: stored procedures r encrypted in oracle database i want to update the encryption key or secret key.

Comment: Alter system set encryption key identified by '<password>' -- does the trick. Thats the master key for the encryption

Comment: (val IN varchar) RETURN varchar AS outstr varchar(10); descr varchar(255); BEGIN -- Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code := '123456788765432112345678'; --create instance of OLE object on an instance of SQL Server; success = 0 EXEC rc = sp_OACreate 'CAPICOM.EncryptedData', object OUT if rc <> 0 begin exec sp_oageterrorinfo object, src out, descr out end method_call := 'SetSecret("' + Secret_code + '")' RETURN (outstr); END; Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code

Comment: i need to update this Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code with some other value.How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures can be WRAPPED which is a form of encryption. But you can't update the key as it is hard-coded into the wrapping algorithm.

This might make you think they are susceptible to be cracked. They are and unwrappers are available.

Comment: (val IN varchar) RETURN varchar AS outstr varchar(10); descr varchar(255); BEGIN -- Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code := '123456788765432112345678'; --create instance of OLE object on an instance of SQL Server; success = 0 EXEC rc = sp_OACreate 'CAPICOM.EncryptedData', object OUT if rc <> 0 begin exec sp_oageterrorinfo object, src out, descr out end method_call := 'SetSecret("' + Secret_code + '")' RETURN (outstr); END; 
I need to update this Encryption Key For Encryption secret_code with some other value.How can i do that .